# C++ class member function to C struct function pointer

Tags: c++, c, struct, function-pointers

I'm trying to make C wrapper in C++.

But I can't convert a function within a class to a struct function pointer.

myCallback function shouldn't be used as static because it have to be overrided.

Here is sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
 typedef struct _client_config
{
    void (*on_connect)(void *client, int result);
} client_config;
}

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() {};
    ~Parent() {};

    virtual void myCallback(void* hello, int world) = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() {};
    ~Child() {};

    void myCallback(void* hello, int world)
    {
        printf("Hello World! \n");
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Parent* myClass = new Child();

    client_config* myClientConfig = (client_config *)malloc(sizeof(client_config));

    myClientConfig->on_connect = myClass->myCallback;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the compiler says during compilation:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'Parent::myCallback': function call missing argument list; use '&Parent::myCallback' to create a pointer to member
Error   2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Parent::* )(void *,int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *,int)'
```

Can anyone point out a way to bind a class member function to a struct function pointer or what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

A C-library's function pointer is compatible with only an `extern "C"` free function.  (Even a static member function is not compatible, the language linkage is wrong).

You'll have to use such a function as a trampoline, ask the object which you receive a pointer to where your object is (the library does provide a way for you to store some form of user-data which can be retrieved inside a callback, doesn't it?  Perhaps that `client` parameter is like this, you'll have to read the documentation.), cast to `Parent*`, and perform the member call.  The compiler will not do this for you.

```
extern "C" void connect_trampoline( void* client, int result )
{
    Parent* my_object = static_cast<Parent*>(client);
    my_object->myCallback(result);
}

myClientConfig->on_connect = &connect_trampoline;
```

C++ libraries are usually coded to make this easier, for example by accepting a `std::function` which can carry state of its own.  But in the C programming style, which C libraries use, you have to find your object and do an ugly cast before using members.

In case the library *doesn't* make some form of pointer under your control accessible to the callback, but does pass a pointer to the library object associated with the callback, you can use a global `std::map<library_object*, Parent*>` to lookup your object.  This approach also avoids the cast.

---

Be careful that when you hand the pointer to your object to the library to hold for you, you give it the same exact type (`Parent*` in this case) that you will cast back later.  If you give a `Derived*`, the effect is that of doing `reinterpret_cast<Parent*>(p_derived)` which is very bad.  (`static_cast` to `void*` when giving the pointer to the library, `static_cast` to `Parent*` when you get it back, and the C++ standard says this sequence is exactly the same behavior as `reinterpret_cast`)